# Can neutrons be manipulated with magnetic fields? Can neutron particle accelerators be built?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, neutrons, dipole-moment, accelerator-physics

Neutrons have no electric charge and do not respond to electric fields as in a conventional particle accelerator.  However, they are magnetic and do have a small magnetic dipole moment.  So it should be possible to apply forces using a suitable magnetic field gradient.  Is it possible to control neutrons in this manner?  Is it possible to build a particle accelerator for neutrons?

I gather from the Wikipedia entry, that neutrons also exhibit electric polarizability.  Does this mean that they develop a dipole moment in the presence of a field?  If so, can they be manipulated and accelerated by a suitable combination of electric field and electric field gradient?

Comment: What final energy do you have in mind? Considering the interaction of a neutron spin with a magnetic field is on the scale of 60 nanovolts/Tesla, you would probably only be able to accelerate neutrons up to microvolts, or millivolts at best using some kind of RF accelerator.

Comment: @KF Gauss Yes, large rapidly-changing fields over a large volume are a problem.   Where does the 60 nV/Tesla come from?

Comment: @KFGauss got it!  E-26 Joules = 60 nanoelectronvolts

Comment: Yes it comes from the Neutron Magnetic moment which is 0.001 Bohr Magneton or ~60nV/T

Comment: @KF Gauss  is "neV" more correct?

Comment: Yes that's right, typically they are used interchangeably, just a matter of whether you talk about energies or voltages (multiply by $e$)

Comment: A former colleague of mine wrote his PhD thesis on that very topic. I'm not sure it's available publicly anywhere, but it's on [ProQuest](https://www.proquest.com/docview/1706912732).

Comment: @mng that's exactly what I was looking for!  Unfortunately I only see the preview.  It would be interesting to know what capabilities were estimated.  You should really try to write it up as an answer.

Comment: I'm afraid it's been too long and my memory fails me. The talks he gave our group were very interesting though, I vaguely remember something about walking-speed neutrons.

Answer (score 1):

I don't oversee the whole math involved, but I think the problem with building an accelerator for neutrons is that this would require to create magnetic fields that are strongly inhomogeneous over a large volume, because of
$$\vec F\sim (\vec m\cdot \nabla)\vec B,$$
which means that the flux densities would have to become enormous very quickly. Also, remember that the dipole field is of order $r^{-3}$ instead of the $r^{-2}$ of the (electric) monopole field.

I guess, there will also be some theorem that what you gain when the magnetic dipole is sucked into the inhomogeneous field, you invariably lose when the dipole leaves the inhomogeneous region. So what is possible for charged particles, namely accelerating them in a homogeneous field and channel them through a pin-hole or something, will not be possible for neutrons.

Comment: If I'm calculating this correctly, with the neutron's magnetic-moment over mass ratio of 5.8 J/T/kg, I'd get an acceleration of 5.8 m/s^2 per Tesla/meter of gradient which is only about 3.5 m/s after one meter of travel.  Also if we're talking about boosting particles close to the speed of light, then traveling fields of this scale and intensity are impossible.  At the other end of the spectrum, how about manipulating/containing very cold neutrons?  Maybe I should post that as a separate question?

Comment: @Roger Wood that's an interesting point regarding cold neutrons. I don't think traps are strictly necessary because ultracold neutrons are reflected from the surfaces of materials, so an ordinary container would work. But interesting idea nonetheless, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultracold_neutrons. Ultimately the problem is that the neutron moment is just really small.